# Exchange / outlook meeting room conflict date/time language reply change

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

[image]

Above is the auto reply message when a domain user tries to book a meeting room using *Outlook*.

My question would be - how to change the language that is in this auto reply (circled in red)? Currently it is in russian and I would like it to be it in english. I haven't found any methods to do this via "Exchange management shell". I've also checked the locale settings with the **Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration** command  via exchange management shell and it is set to en-US for all the meeting rooms and domain users who get this auto reply when they try to book.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You may have a look at this TechNet thread which provided some methods you can try: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/168e9ada-8a73-4b88-9f10-5a3a1b49c719/meeting-room-emails-are-in-german-date-format-not-english?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy

Comment: @SteveFan thanks, but no help from that thread, i suspect that the server locale language could be set to russian..